# Adding images to something similar to UITextField or other text input view

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextview

I'm looking to intersperse some images amongst text in a text input view.  I want the user to be able to type in text and at any time, to tap my provided camera button which would insert an image into the text at that point.  The user can then continue typing in text, and again, be able to insert more images when and where they please.

I want the user to be able to move the insertion point anywhere in this text/image mixture, to select text, image or a combination of the two (as long as it is contiguous), and use the keyboard to type more text, add an image, delete text or image(s), etc.  Basically, I want the functionality found in the iPhone Messages app, in the view that the user is provided to type text or add images.

Once the user is done, I can be flexible as to what format I take away.  I would be happy with an array of objects, `NSString` or `UIImage` objects, ordered as was entered.

I've already tried to create my own view with different `UITextField` or `UITextView`s and `UIImageView`s added as needed.  I also tried doing it with a `UITableView`, one row per text or image.  The problem is that I don't get the expected selection or caret insertion behavior.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this.

Here is how it looks in the Messages app:
[image: Here is how it looks in the Messages app:]

Comment: You are definitely going to have to <shudder>style a UIWebView</shudder>

Comment: Yeah, that would be difficult (UIWebView that is).  There is no support for text entry, but it does provide support for selection though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like [OmniUI](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad). It is a heavy, powerful and complex framework. I'm not sure it supports iPhone.